# Linkedin OAUTH Randomly fails with Internal Service Error

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

We have been using Oauth with Linkedin for years and recently we have noticed that it randomly will fail with a 500 Internal Service Error for ~1 out of 100 people.  It will fail for the same users over and over again even if they had logged in before. My guess is that there is something specific about those users that causes the issue.

I know my oauth setup is working because it works for 99% of users.  I probably need a linkedin engineer to weight in on this but anyone else who has had experiences like this would be helpful.

Below is a the result of the calls:

```
{"errorCode"=>0,
"message"=>"Internal service error",
"requestId"=>"92LHE2E7H2",
"status"=>500,
"timestamp"=>1447360584670},
{"errorCode"=>0,
"message"=>"Internal service error",
"requestId"=>"LZ7BJBW2FS",
"status"=>500,
"timestamp"=>1447360791073},
{"errorCode"=>0,
"message"=>"Internal service error",
"requestId"=>"93EFYRXAF1",
"status"=>500,
"timestamp"=>1447360956028},
{"errorCode"=>0,
"message"=>"Internal service error",
"requestId"=>"RVW4W5CVJU",
"status"=>500,
"timestamp"=>1447361645555},
{"errorCode"=>0,
"message"=>"Internal service error",
"requestId"=>"WFA4NBIAC9",
"status"=>500,
"timestamp"=>1447362398692},
{"errorCode"=>0,
"message"=>"Internal service error",
"requestId"=>"H6G55JYMLR",
"status"=>500,
"timestamp"=>1447363655108},
```

Answer (score 0):

We noticed the same thing for some of our users.  We were able to narrow it down to users who did not have at a minimum "basics" selected for their LinkedIn "public" profile visibility.  We have had users for years that did not have a public profile enabled in their LinkedIn profile and we never had any issues until recently - so we are guessing this is a recent CHANGE or BUG on LinkedIn's side.  We now capture this and let the user know that either LinkedIn is down or that the user needs to enable their public profile (basics).